# How to read data from a mysql table in c#?

Tags: c#

When I start the program I always get this error: could not find specified column in results:firstname.

I changed "firstname" for any other column and it is giving me the same error. I have tested the connection also and the connection is properly written.

```
 public partial class frmDashboard : Form
{
    public frmDashboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public frmDashboard(string user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=mydb;user=root;Pwd=carolle;SslMode=none");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select upper(customer.firstname) from mydb.customer where customer.email = '" + user + "';");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        connect.Open();
        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                lblusername.Text = dr.GetString("firstname");

            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: try changing `firstname` to `0`

Comment: I'd like to suggest you to use some ORM framework that will hide db connections (like [EF](https://entityframework.net) or [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) ). Also it is bad practive - to create db connections in the form. It would be better to move the data load save logic to the dedicated class.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to your use of `upper` which changes the result set.

Using an alias with `AS` can fix this.

```
SELECT upper(customer.firstname) AS firstname FROM mydb.customer WHERE customer.email = '"+ user + "';"
```

Also you should be using parameters, not string concatenation, when creating queries for a wide variety of reasons including security and type safety.

If you prefer you can retrieve columns using indexes instead, changing

```
dr.GetString("firstname");
```

to

```
dr.GetString(0);
```

The column index corresponds to the ordering of columns in the `SELECT` statement.